# Ways to interact with my kid

Tags: social-development, working-parents

I'm living in Spain and my kid is with my wife back in Brazil for now (they will join me later).

The hardest feeling I have is that I'm not interacting with my kid as much as I would like to, we try some Skype calls and stuff but as hes only 4 yo it's hard to keep his attention.

Do you have any suggestions of things we could do together remotely?

---

I have created the same question in Expatriates Q&A and was told to create it here too:
https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6477/ways-to-interact-with-my-kid/

Answer (score 3):

I never thought about it before, so here are a few things that just popped into my mind :

- You can maybe play "hide & seek" : your wife hide the device somewhere while still connected and your kid has to find "you" back
- sing-a-long
- with a little organisation you can probably also read him a book (while your wife turns the pages)
- have him make and send some drawings to you, once you get them you can show him through skype you got it and how glad you are
- Putting the laptop on the table, you can also probably share a "21th century family dinner"...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions!
We already do some of these, like dinning together and sing-a-long (when skype helps), also the book reading (as he's 4yo he turns the pages himself), and the drawing thing as well.
They were all really nice suggestions (+1), but all of these are activities grabs his attentions for a few minutes only, I'd like to see other suggestions that could make him interested for longer period.